# Authenticate an EWS application by using OAuth - Limited Mailboxes

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, office365, exchangewebservices

Is it possible to limit the user mailboxes accessible by the application permissions via EWS API (not Graph API)?
And how can this be done?

Comment: No you can't do it with the EWS API its a legacy API so can't take advantage of scoping

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Is there a reference doc somewhere. Wasnt able to find this anywhere hence asking here.

Comment: Its not a feature that was ever available in EWS hence no documentation only https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access . You can scope down EWS Impersonation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-configure-impersonation?redirectedfrom=MSDN but you would still have to use a Service Account and delegate access.